# How can I make ctrl+left/right keys to move by whole word in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

In both zsh and bash, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd> allows me to move the position I'm typing at by whole word, but this does not work in tmux, which is a problem as I'm currently launching it automatically every time I open a shell.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

1. Edit your `~/.tmux.conf` and add lines:

   ```
   set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
   ```
2. If you don’t want to make it permanent just yet, do:

   ```
   C-b :set-window-option xterm-keys on
   ```
3. Reload your config in tmux by doing:

   ```
   C-b :source-file ~/.tmux.conf
   ```

More information [here](http://www.sigizmund.com/2012/02/tmux-and-c-leftc-right.html):

Comment: Strange: This works for me only if I reload the ~/.tmux.conf file from tmux or set the action in the :-prompt of tmux, not initially when I open tmux. Any ideas what might be the problem there?

Comment: @AME close all tmux sessions then try again.

Comment: If reload config doesn't fix the problem (this is the case for me), try a new session. Maybe you need to kill the current session and create a new one. Another option to make it take effect in a pane (not a session) is C-b: respawn-pane -k

Comment: This worked for me, mostly. I wonder why it's not on by default?

Comment: Killing the session, or whatever `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` still doesn't do anything in my case.

Comment: press `C-b` then `kill-server` or `tmux kill-server` before testing the result

Comment: This didnt work for me.  when sshing into a remote tmux session meta left/right prints ;3D ;3C

Answer (score 12):

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

Got me some of the way there and gave me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> on the console, but it was still responding differently in vim.

Unbinding the keys didn't seem to help.

It turned out that at some point I had set my default terminal to screen (`set-option -g default-terminal "screen"` in `.tmux.conf`)

Changing this to the following gave me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> in everything else:

```
set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Except this breaks colors in vim, tig, and presumably a whole bunch of other stuff...

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1098/250 for an advice against setting TERM like that in tmux

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but this might be because `tmux` by default binds `C-<up/down/left/right>` to shift the focus onto the pane above/below/left of/right of the currently focused pane. If you don't use panes often, you might not have noticed this feature. If this is what the problem is, you can unbind those keys by saying:

```
unbind C-Left
unbind C-Right
```

**That might be enough on it's own**, or you might need to manually bind them again to what you want them to do, via:

```
bind -n C-Left <the action you want>
bind -n C-Right <other action you want>
```

Comment: It should be enough on it's own, if it isn't grabbed by tmux, it should pass onto the shell.

Answer (score 3):

For msys2/Cygwin/mintty:

Add below to `~/.inputrc`.

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word   # ctrl + right
"\e[1;5D": backward-word  # ctrl + left
```

Reload would make tmux work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the keys were not being bound correctly, because the system preferences in High Sierra were set to being used by Mission Control.
Unchecking these then allowed the correct bindings to work in iTerm2 and Tmux

[image: System Preferences]

Unchecking all of the items referencing the control key, allowed the bindings to work properly

Comment: Not sure where OSX or Iterm2 were mentioned by OP.