# Get Ctrl+Arrow to work under tmux+urxvt

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, tmux, urxvt

I have tmux command key as C-a. C-Left/C-Right to jump between words (or whatever it is called) works just fine in urxvt alone, but under urxvt/tmux it'll print '5D' and '5C' for Left/Right respectively. How do I configure tmux so word skipping works (either with on X with urxvt or in a tty)?

Comment: What program are you typing the C-Left and C-Right into? If it is a shell, which shell it is? Does its configuration have any bindings (i.e. `bind` in *bash* and `bindkey` in *zsh*)? What TERM are you using inside your *tmux* panes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make ctrl+left/right keys work right in tmux?](http://superuser.com/questions/360832/how-can-i-make-ctrlleft-right-keys-work-right-in-tmux)

Answer (score 15):

Add this to your `.Xdefaults`

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Up:     \033[1;5A
URxvt.keysym.Control-Down:   \033[1;5B
URxvt.keysym.Control-Left:   \033[1;5D
URxvt.keysym.Control-Right:  \033[1;5C
```

URxvt will now send the same escape sequences as XTerm.

This will make sure that word-jumping will even work when you are connected to a remote maching with its own `.inputrc` using SSH.

For making urxvt act more like xterm see http://www.netswarm.net/misc/urxvt-xtermcompat.txt

Comment: I added it to `~/.Xresources`, ran `cat ~/.Xresources | xrdb -merge` and restarted the terminal. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from [Ctrl-left and Ctrl-right in bash and Emacs](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2006/10/05/ctrl-left-and-ctrl-right-in-bash-and-emacs/):

```
Sometimes the small things make a big difference. I noticed that the control-left 
and control-right keys weren’t working in bash or Emacs on my FreeBSD box 
accessed over X11.app on OS X. Easily fixed.

.inputrc

    "\e[1;5C": forward-word     # Ctrl+right  => forward word
    "\e[1;5D": backward-word    # Ctrl+left   => backward word

.emacs

    (global-set-key "\M-[1;5C"    'forward-word)  ; Ctrl+right   => forward word
    (global-set-key "\M-[1;5D"    'backward-word) ; Ctrl+left    => backward word
```

- I guess you'd need to do that in each programs and change their key bindings.
- I don't know why `tmux` mangles the keystrokes going through though.

Answer (score 2):

If you use zsh, add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey "5C" forward-word
bindkey "5D" backward-word
```

Got it from http://clock.co.uk/blog/zsh-ctrl-left-arrow-outputting-5d

Comment: This worked for me.  Previous posts (.Xresouces, .xinputrc) did not.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://superuser.com/a/395273/65499

```
C-b :set-window-option xterm-keys on
```